# Is it possible to pass Integer Array via Navigation Component DeepLink?

Tags: android, deep-linking, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation, android-deep-link

I'm trying the DeepLink solution (and someplace I already have DeepLink implemented), but now the problem is the targeted destination I'm trying to go has params with an array of integer, How can add integer[] in DeepLink Uri path parameter like the following:

```xml
<argument
        android:name="references"
        app:argType="integer[]"
        app:nullable="false" />
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy option is to encode your array to a JSON string, pass it as a string parameter, and decode the string in the destination back to the array. Use Gson or Kotlin serialization for encoding / decoding.

Comment: That's not much efficient in my case, As it will require various code modification within the library modules.